# Xcode crashes when I try to Add New Version of Core Data model

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have the latest version of Xcode and when I select my .xcdatamodel file and then select "Data Model" => "Add Model Version", I get the following dialog:

Internal Error

File: ...
Line: ...
Object: ...
Method: ...

Couldn't create new version 'MyApp1 2.xcdatamodel' in version group 'MyApp1.xcdatamodeld'

=====================

It wiped out the old .xcdatamodel directory and created a new .xcdatamodeld directory, but there is nothing it it.

Fortunately I have an old copy of the original directory and I can restore it with little difficulty, but I need to update the schema in a way that will migrate old versions.

Any idea of how I can do this by hand?

Comment: Well, I just manually created the "2" directory under the xcdatamodeld directory and populated it w/the files from the original version and then added everything back into xcode and it seems ok.  Still puzzled why it crashed.

Comment: File a crash report at http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem, although I did retain my models in the xcdatamodeld resource group. I had to drag that resource back into Xcode. Then replaced 
`- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel;` 
in my appDelegate with the following code...

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
    return managedObjectModel;
}

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"your_model" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];

return managedObjectModel;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This was happening to my project when the Project Format is set to Xcode 3.2-compatible. This setting is under the info window, Project Format drop down. I had changed it from the default, for not particular reason.

Setting it back to the default, Xcode 3.1-compatible, made the problem go away for me. I'm using 3.2.4 and the iOS 4.1 GM SDK.